# How to link button with labels in tkinter without explicitly declaring them as variables

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to link my buttons with labels, however I am not allowed to explicitly declare them as variables because I will use loop for it (e.g. number of button-label pair will depend on user input).

```
for i in range(desired_number):
    button = tk.Button(self.mainframe)
    button.grid(row = i, column = 0)
    label = tk.Label(self.mainframe)
    label.grid(row = i, column = 1)

    button.config(command = lambda: self.changetext(label))

@staticmethod
def changetext(label):
    label.config(text="button on my left has been pressed")
```

this however doesn't work. It seems that I can't just pass the object, but also have to pass the explicit name for it. Any idea on tackling this?

Comment: search this site for questions about creating buttons in loops. This question has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a parameter to your lambda. This way it should use each button seperately rather than just the last button/label defined. Simple executable example below

```
import tkinter as tk

def changetext(label):
    label.config(text="button on my left has been pressed")

root = tk.Tk()
desired_number = 5

for i in range(desired_number):
    button = tk.Button(root,text=f"Button {i}")
    button.grid(row = i, column = 0)
    label = tk.Label(root)
    label.grid(row = i, column = 1)
    button.config(command = lambda x=label: changetext(x))


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically created widgets, you can store them in a array for later access. In this case, you can pass the label index to the button handler.

```
lstbtn = []
lstlbl = []

for i in range(desired_number):
    button = tk.Button(self.mainframe)
    button.grid(row = i, column = 0)
    lstbtn.append(button)  # save for later
    label = tk.Label(self.mainframe)
    label.grid(row = i, column = 1)
    lstlbl.append(label)  # save for later

    button.config(command = lambda: self.changetext(i)) # pass label index

@staticmethod
def changetext(idx):  # label index
    lstlbl[idx].config(text="button on my left has been pressed")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.8+ you can use a walrus (`:=`) and accomplish what you want on 2 lines. It doesn't matter that the `Label` is being added to the `grid` before the `Button`. Their `grid` positions were defined and those are the positions they will reside in.

Using names like `desired_count` and `change_label` is too generic. I changed those names to better reflect what they refer to.

```
import tkinter as tk

def indicate_button(label):
    label['text'] = 'corresponding button pressed'
    
root = tk.Tk()
combo_count = 5

for i in range(combo_count):
    (lbl := tk.Label(root, width=25)).grid(row=i, column=1)
    tk.Button(root, text=f"Button {i}", command=lambda L=lbl: indicate_button(L)).grid(row=i, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Another way to do this would be to store the `Label` in a list. I realize this answer was already given, but their version is messy, incomplete and has errors. I also extended the example to show how this could be useful.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
combo_count = 5

labels  = [None]*combo_count

def indicate_button(i):
    if i < len(labels) and labels[i]:
        for n, lbl in enumerate(labels):
            #assign target label and clear the others
            lbl['text'] = 'corresponding button pressed' if n == i else ''
    else:
        #do something about an out of range or empty index
        pass    

for i in range(combo_count):
    labels[i] = tk.Label(root, width=25)
    labels[i].grid(row=i, column=1)
    tk.Button(root, text=f'Button {i}', command=lambda i=i: indicate_button(i)).grid(row=i, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```